ns3でスマートポインタがnullptrであると返された．
ns3で通信ノードのキュー長を取得するコードで，以下の"wifiMac"がnullptrだと返されてしまいます．
これの対処法をご教授いただければ幸いです．
Ptr<NetDevice> device = netDevice.Get(i);
Ptr<WifiNetDevice> wifiDevice = DynamicCast<WifiNetDevice>(device);

Ptr<WifiMac> mac = wifiDevice->GetMac();

Ptr<WifiMacQueue> wifiMac = DynamicCast<WifiMacQueue>(mac);

if (wifiMac == nullptr){
    std::cerr << "Error: wifiMac is null pointer." << endl;
}

また，以下の箇所でも同様のエラーが発生します．
Ptr<PacketSink> sink = node->GetObject<PacketSink>();
uint64_t totalReceived = sink->GetTotalRx();


dynamic_cast　を使えば、nullptr　だと返される場合は、どこかタイプを使うこととの間違いがあるそうです。WifiMac　本当に　WifiMacQueue　の子孫ですか。もしここで間違いがなければ、WifiMac　と　WifiMacQueue　のコードを付けていただけませんか。

なぜキャストできると考えたのかわかりませんが、WifiMacQueueはWifiMacの派生クラスでも基底クラスでもないのでは？
